# The IntlPhoneField search text can't be shown

Tags: flutter

I'm using `IntlPhoneField` to get the user's phone number based on the country they choose. But when I click the dropdown list to change the country, all the countries' names and the search text I type are white colored and the background color is also white. I tried a LOT in all text styles to change the color, but it didn't work. May I get help, please?

[image]